# serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout

Tags: esp32

Sketch uses 260925 bytes (24%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 27984 bytes (34%) of dynamic memory, leaving 53936 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.

```
esptool.py v3.0
Serial port COM3
Connecting...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vicky/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.2/tools/pyserial\serial\serialwin32.py", line 325, in write
    raise SerialTimeoutException('Write timeout')
serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

I want to upload `Blink Code` in "ESP - 12E" model but getting this error.